# How to run a script on multiple files matching a regex?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have a general question regarding pattern matching in Linux.
Say, I have a script through which I want to run many files in succession, that is run like this:

```
./script -i file1 -j file2
```

I have many pairs of files which are identical in name apart from the last two characters, for example file1 ends in `-1` and file2 in `-2`.

`-` does not appear in any other place of the filename so I am thinking there should be a way of piping all the pairs of files through the script using regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your folder with all the files:

```
$ ls
fileA-1   fileB-1   fileC-1
fileA-2   fileB-2   fileC-2
```

do the following:

```
for file1 in *-1
do
    # This will remove the trailing '1' from the file and append a '2'
    # learn more about parameter substitution at
    # http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html
    file2="${file1%1}2"

    #execute!
    ./script -i "$file1" -j "$file2"
done
```